# How to access sql column that is in a map,string,struct,array,string

Tags: sql, presto, regex-replace

I have a table in sql that is map,string,struct,array,string.
I have accessed the value by using element_at(k,v) which works.
My issue is the column has values like '#"nike"#','#"REEBOK"#'.
I have tried stripping the characters(,#),
I have tried `regex_extract` and `regex_replace`, but I keep getting the error:

> Unexpected parameters(map(varchar(row(input
> varchar(input(array(varchar),input,textinput() expected
> element_at(array(E), element_map(K,V),K)K,V

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '"[^"]*"', '')
FROM table;
```

is there a way to strip or extract the words in between the " " characters?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Athena presto sql

Comment: Can you please add sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[#"]', '') AS cleaned_col
FROM table;
```